# Improve the query

Tags: c#, lambda, .net-4.5, bulk

I have two List. One with new objects, lets call it NewCol, and one that I have read out of my database(lets call it CurrentCol). The CurrentCol is about 1.2 million rows(and will grow daily) and the NewCol can be any thing from 1 to thousands of rows at a time. Can any one please help me improve the following code as it runs way too slow:

```
foreach (PortedNumberCollection element in NewCol)
{
    if (CurrentCol.AsParallel().Select(x => x.MSISDN).Contains(element.MSISDN))
    {
        CurrentCol.AsParallel().Where(y => y.MSISDN == element.MSISDN)
            .Select
                (x =>
                    {      
                       //if the MSISDN exists in both the old and new collection
                       // then update the old collection                                              
                       x.RouteAction = element.RouteAction;
                       x.RoutingLabel = element.RoutingLabel;
                       return x;
                    }
                 );
    }
    else
    {
        //The item does not exist in the old collection so add it
        CurrentCol.Add(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely an inner join would speed things up... var query = (from cc in CurrentCol  join nc in NewCol on cc.MSISDN  select nc.MSISDN).ToList();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a pretty bad idea to read the whole database into memory and search it there. Searching is what databases are optimized for. The best thing you can do is to move that whole code into the database somehow, for example by executing a [MERGE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28SQL%29) statement for each item in `NewCol`.

---

However, if you can't do that, the next best thing would be to make `CurrentCol` a dictionary with `MSISDN` as the key:

```
// Somewhere... Only once, not every time you want to add new items
// In fact, there shouldn't be any CurrentCol, only the dictionary.
var currentItems = CurrentCol.ToDictionary(x => x.MSISDN, x => x);

// ...

foreach(var newItem in NewCol)
{
    PortedNumberCollection existingItem;
    if(currentItems.TryGetValue(newItem.MSISDN, out existingItem)
    {
        existingItem.RouteAction = newItem.RouteAction;
        existingItem.RoutingLabel = newItem.RoutingLabel;
    }
    else
    {
        currentItems.Add(newItem.MSISDN, newItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not reading the whole database into memory only one table that has three columns. I am reading it into cache and using it amongst several services... once a day a new file will need to be downloaded and amended to the existing list. Hence the need to read the entire list to memory.